# what is the integration of fifth root of $\tan(x)$ i.e. $\tan^{\frac{1}{5}}(x)$.

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

what is the suggested method for this. I have used the substitution $$\tan(x)= z^{\frac{2}{5}}.$$ But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$\sqrt[5]{\tan(x)}=t$$ then we get
$$x=\arctan(t^5)$$ and $$dx=5\,{\frac {{t}^{4}}{{t}^{10}+1}}dt$$ and our integral will be
$$5\int \frac{t^5}{t^{10}+1}dt$$